# How to use bluebird with IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack, bluebird, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack to bundle things. It seems to work well in every other browser, but in IE (which doesn't have promises), it gives error that it cant find `Promise`.

I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject all scripts. Hence my app's scripts are always injected towards the end. However, in my app chunk, it appears to have this code (found this by searching inside unminified-files using the cdn url link):

```
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($, Promise) {(function() {

var getFormFieldsFor, handleFileSelect, uploadFile, uniqid, OnComplete;
var displayUploadProgress, setCaptionText, initProgressBar, resetProgressBar;

var handleAlbumUpload, handleVideoUpload, handleAudioUpload;

/** IE doesn't support Promises in ES5', bluebird alternative script can handle it */
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv 11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1)) {
        var script=document.createElement('script');
        script.type='text/javascript';
        script.src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.5/bluebird.min.js';
        $("body").append(script);
    }
});
```

It seems to dynamically insert another `script` tag at end of my DOM upon page load. Since my previous scripts already passed execution, they give error that `Promise` cannot be found. This behavior is not seen in any other browser (even the code does specific checks for IE).

Is there a way to use bluebird without causing this behavior? I am aiming for IE10+ compatibility with promises (tested on IE11). Or will I have to go for another promise library?

I do not think that my webpack config would be much relevant here, but let me know if its required.

Comment: your code specifically loads Bluebird on document ready in IE ... of course it's too late by then

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. But what I am asking is, is there a way so it won't do that? So that bluebird will run on its own without injecting this cdn. Also, this isn't my code. I just use simple `imports` to import bluebird. Bluebird injects this code automatically somehow. So is what I am asking possible? Maybe using an older version?

Comment: If you want to load something synchronously, then you have to use either a `<script>` tag present in the original HTML or you have to insert one with `document.write()`.  Appending it like the code you show will load is asynchronously and it will not be be present when other synchronously loaded code is loaded.